# How to calculate RPG Level Progression as percentage

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

I'm designing an RPG game where a user may accumulate experience points (XP) and level up, based on XP. Calculating the current level is trivial; `if else` seems to be most efficent.

**I would like to calculate percent of progression for the current level.** Based on the assumption that I have 10 levels, where each level is capped at a somewhat exponential value:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RPGLevelCap) {
    RPGLevelCap1=499,
    RPGLevelCap2=1249,
    RPGLevelCap3=2249,
    RPGLevelCap4=3499,
    RPGLevelCap5=4999,
    RPGLevelCap6=6999,
    RPGLevelCap7=9999,
    RPGLevelCap8=14999,
    RPGLevelCap9=19999,
    RPGLevelCap10=19999 // Anything beyond previous level is Lvl 10; display as 100%
};
```

What's an efficient, yet easily understandable way, to calculate a user's level progression based on their current level?

An `if else` statement is both hard to understand and maintain, but may be fairly efficient:

```
float levelProgression=0;

// Calculate level progression as a fraction of 1
if(xp <= RPGLevelCap1)
{
    levelProgression = ((float)xp / RPGLevelCap1);
}
else if (xp <=RPGLevelCap2)
{
    levelProgression = ((float)(xp-RPGLevelCap1) / (RPGLevelCap2-RPGLevelCap1));
}
else if (xp <=RPGLevelCap3)
{
    levelProgression = ((float)(xp-RPGLevelCap2) / (RPGLevelCap3-RPGLevelCap2));
}

...

else if (xp>RPGLevelCap10)
{
    levelProgression = 1;
}
```

Given that the level caps are inconsistent...how should I handle this problem?

Comment: Using an array to store level caps might make it easier

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. A simple way would be to store the level cap values in an array. Find the player's current level based on the largest value it's less than. (level one is 0 to 499, level two is 500 to 1249, etc.) Use a loop to find the user's level rather than a set of if/else statements.

Then calculate the range of the player's current level, (end_of_range - start_of_range)

```
0 - 499 = 499
500 - 1249 = 749,
```

etc.

If a player is at 600 points, he's a level 2 character, in the 500-1249 range.

He's at 600-500 or 100 points into the range. (600-500)/749*100 is the player's percent complete in that range. 13.35% complete, in this example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can approach this. My weapon of choice here is to embody the XP values within the concept of LevelData versus using an enum, array of XP values, etc. The benefit of something like this is that for each level, you'll typically have many configurable values (for example level based multipliers) based on level. This way they are all in once place.

In your LevelData, there are different ways you can encode XP. These range from the XP total for the next level, or the beginning and end XP total for the next level. Obviously there are other permutations of this.

I usually use the later, mainly because it prevents me from having to "know" the LevelData for the previous level.

So I would typically have this in JSON

```
{
    "levelData": [
    {
        "levelStartXP": "0",
        "levelUpXP": "250",
        "levelUpBonus": 0
    },
    {
        "levelStartXP": "250",
        "levelUpXP": "1000",
        "levelUpBonus": 50
    },
    {
        "levelStartXP": "1000",
        "levelUpXP": "2500",
        "levelUpBonus": 100
    },
    ]
}
```

This is just a boring example. I then of course have a LevelData class which is embodies each level. I also have a LevelDataManager. That manager is used to vend out information per level. Having convenience methods help. For examples, good ones to have are:

```
- (NSInteger)levelWithXP:(NSInteger)xp; // for a given XP, give me the appropriate level
- (LevelData *)levelDataWithXP:(NSInteger)xp; //for a given XP, give me the appropriate LevelData
- (LevelData *)levelDataWithLevel:(NSInteger)level; // for a given level, give me the appropriate LevelData
- (NSInteger)levelUpXPForLevel:(NSInteger)level; // for a given level, give me the XP value needed for the next level)
```

I just arbitrarily used `NSInteger`, use the appropriate data type for your case.

Just what you want to support is really up to you.

The gist of the whole thing is try not to store individual level components. Rather aggregate them in LevelData or some other collection, so you have all the info per level at your disposal and create some form of manager/interface to get you the information you need.

So back to you your question. Let's say we have a class for LevelData (assume it is using the JSON above, and those fields are represented by properties) and a LevelDataManager instance called theLevelDataMgr, you could compute the % based on something like:

```
LevelData *levelData = [theLevelDataMgr levelDataWithLevel:currLevel]; // currLevel is the current level
float xpDiffInLevel = levelData.levelUpXP - levelStartXP;
float xpInLevel = currXP - levelStartXP; // currXP is the current XP of the user
float pctOfXP = xpInLevel / xpDiffInLevel; // You should add divide by zero check
```

And yes, if you wanted, you could have the LevelData class contain a method to do this calculation for you to help encapsulate it even better.

Code isn't tested and is listed to just give you a better idea on how to do it. Also, how you decide to store your XP for each level dictates how this would work. This code is based on the method I usually use.